# Incorrect combinatorial argument- 5 card hand with at least 3 red cards

Tags: combinatorics, fake-proofs

How many 5 card hands can be made with at least three red cards?  Of course, we're using a standard deck of 52.  I know how to answer this, but I frequently see this argument, producing a different answer.  I know it's wrong but I can't explain exactly what's wrong with it?

"First, there are $_{52}C_3$ of choosing three red cards.  Since the other two cards can be black or red, we can choose them from any of the 49 unused cards.  I.e. $_{49}C_2$ ways.  So the final answer should be $_{52}C_3$  x   $_{49}C_2$"

Comment: I realize you are trying to illustrate a common mistake when you write: "First there are 52 choose 3 ... "

Comment: but did you mean: First there are 26 choose 3 ways to select 3 red cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This counting argument is incorrect because it will multiple-count configurations for which more than three cards are red; e.g., $$\{10\color{red}\heartsuit, J\color{red}\heartsuit, Q\color{red}\heartsuit, K\color{red}\heartsuit, A\color{red}\heartsuit\} = \{\{10\color{red}\heartsuit, J\color{red}\heartsuit, Q\color{red}\heartsuit \}, \{K\color{red}\heartsuit, A\color{red}\heartsuit\}\} = \{\{10\color{red}\heartsuit, J\color{red}\heartsuit\}, \{ Q\color{red}\heartsuit, K\color{red}\heartsuit, A\color{red}\heartsuit\}\}$$ but under such an enumeration scheme, the middle and right hand expressions are considered distinct.

Comment: The correct answer is 1299480 obtained by considering the cases: exactly 3 red cards, exactly 4 red cards, and exactly 5 red cards?